# Error with Named Pipes is not caught in try/catch

Tags: c#, pipe, try-catch, named-pipes

I am using the following code snippet to send data over a Named Pipe in :

```
public void send(byte[] message, int timeOut = 1000)
{
    try
    {
        NamedPipeClientStream pipeStream = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "TestPipe1234", PipeDirection.Out, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);

        pipeStream.Connect(timeOut);
        pipeStream.BeginWrite(message, 0, message.Length, aSyncSend, pipeStream);
    }
    catch (TimeoutException ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Sometimes, I receive the following error :

> System.IO.IOException: The semaphore timeout period has expired.
>
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>
> at System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream.Connect(Int32 timeout)
>
> [...]

I am not sure when this happens (nobody listening to the other side ?) BUT in any case I don't understand why this error is not caught by the try catch block.

Do you have any idea of what is happening ? Any help is welcome.

Comment: use simple catch. catch (Exception)
    {
          }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
try
{
    NamedPipeClientStream pipeStream = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "TestPipe1234", PipeDirection.Out, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);

    pipeStream.Connect(timeOut);
    pipeStream.BeginWrite(message, 0, message.Length, aSyncSend, pipeStream);
}
catch (Exception)
{
}
```